# https status code 200 but response is null

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, https

I'm using SpringMVC with https. I have the following `AuthenticationIntercepter`

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (!request.getRequestURI().contains("/common")
            && !request.getRequestURI().equals("/login")
            && !request.getRequestURI().equals("/logout")) {
        String token = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            if (hasKey(token)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

XML configuration

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
        <bean class="XX.AuthenticationInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

if I use authenticationIntercaptor, https status code=200 but response is `null` else  is ok. Why?

Comment: When `preHandle` return `false`, it will return a empty `200 OK` response unless you change the response using `HttpServletResponse` parameter

Comment: how use response ?